# Meteor.js - Serve image directly from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using Meteor.js, how can I serve an arbitrary HTTP response, eg. an image or PDF?

Example 1 - I need to generate PDF reports, which I cannot store in public/ or on a third-party server. Or, the report may be generated live in response to a HTTP GET.

Example 2 - If I have a url like:

```
/images/myimage.png
```

I would like to detect that request on the server, read the image from MongoDB, and serve it with the correct headers, so it is available to use with img tags, ie.

```
<img src="/images/myimage.png">
```

I do not want to store the images in the /public/ directory, so that I can have more control over exactly what is served and how it is permissioned.

**Edit** I was also able to get a basic example working using Iron Router.

```
ImageController = RouteController.extend({
    run: function() {
      var f = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/image.png");
      var res = this.response;
      res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "image/png" });
      res.write(f);
      res.end();  
    }
});

Router.map(function() {
  Router.route("images", {
    path: "/images/image.png",
    where: "server",
    controller: ImageController // Note - cannot use string here - Iron Router has a dependency on window
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write the response code as in any node app, using the middleware:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice (0, 0, {
  route: '/path/to/the/file',
  handle: function(req, res, next) {

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': ...ITEM TYPE... ,
    });
    res.write( ...ITEM DATA... );
    res.end();

  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filepicker. In filepicker the upload images is save in the bucket(cloud) and returns the url of that image. You can save the url in your mongo database. and when you want to use that image just use `<img src="{{saveurl}}" >` .
For more help see the documentation https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/